# JavaScript Protractor (Selenium) verify if input is focused

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm trying to to test whether an element is focused using selenium webdriver in protractor. This is before AngularJS is loaded so I am having to use the driver as seen here:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance(),
    driver = ptor.driver;
```

I also need to know how to make the test wait until the input is focused. I have to wait until a model is fired so the input is not focused for half a second as seen here:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $("input#email").focus();
}, 500);
```

Any idea how to verify if an input has focus after 500ms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assert an element is focused?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753496/how-do-i-assert-an-element-is-focused)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756276/3049002), and adapting it to your case, it would look like:

```js
it('should focus on foo input', function () {
    // to wait 500ms+
    browser.driver.sleep(600);

    // using the Protractor 'element' helper
    // https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#element
    // var input = element(by.id('foo'));

    // using findElement with protractor instance
    var input = driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('foo'));

    expect(input.getAttribute('id')).toEqual(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Comment: This got it. Thanks!  There is a bit of a difference in syntax for the getting element by ID and the second to last line needs an extra parenthesis but other than that it worked like a charm.

Adding another answer below with the correct syntax and parentheses below. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer to fix this missing parenthesis ;) And I guess the short `element(by.id())` syntax did not work for you because angular is not loaded in your case?

Comment: That's correct. In my use case, the login modal is fired on the marketing site, which is outside of Angular. Thanks again!

Comment: assertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) }

Answer (score 0):

I used [glepretre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756467/2104168), but had to resolve the getAttribute promises for both elements using promise.all

```
let activeElement = browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id');
let compareElement = element(by.id('your-element-id')).getAttribute('id'); 
webdriver.promise.all([compareElement, activeElement]).then((id) => {
    expect(id[0]).to.equal(id[1]);
});
```