# How do I assert an element is focused?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am attempting to verify that the focused element is set on page load as one of my tests.

This seems to be working, and I can verify with the element explorer, but the Jasmine matchers don't seem to pick up on this.

Here's my code:

```
var LoginPage = function () {
    this.basePath = browser.params.baseUrl;
    this.loginPart = "/#/login";
    this.usernameInput = element(by.model('username'));

    this.get = function () { ... }
}

it('should focus on the username field on load', function () {
     loginPage.get();
     expect(loginPage.usernameInput).toBe(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement());
});
```

The field itself is correctly getting focus when the page loads (and element explorer correctly allows me to query this via `browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement()`, so I think this test should be passing, but it isn't.

Instead I get an enormous stacktrace which doesn't offer any useful information.

Comment: What happens with `expect(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement()).toBe(loginPage.usernameInput)` ?

Comment: @ivarni - I get `Error: expect called with WebElement argment, expected a Promise. Did you mean to use .getText()?` rather than the big stacktrace.

Comment: OK, I was thinking maybe the problem was that `.switchTo().activeElement()` had some kind of asynchronous side-effect and the the focus wasn't actually changed untill after the expect was evaluated, but that wasn't the case then.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I found a workaround:

Since `expect` expects to be called with a promise, you can compare some attribute of the two webElements (your input and the currently `activeElement`) :

```
it('should focus on the username field on load', function () {
     loginPage.get();
     expect(loginPage.usernameInput.getAttribute('id')).toEqual(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getAttribute('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured I could do something like that, just wished there was a way of testing element equality without relying on attributes. I guess this does the same job, but it also relies on me having set a unique attribute.

Comment: I suppose I could probably do `.getInnerHtml()` or `.getOuterHtml()` which would achieve the same thing.

Comment: I understand, that's why I said it was only a workaround ;). Yes, you can compare the inner or outer HTML too if you prefer

Comment: Hey @glepretre, if you have time, please take a look at the follow-up to your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679364/asserting-an-element-is-focused. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this nice simple function to assert focus.

```
var expectToBeFocused = function(element){
  return expect(element.getInnerHtml()).
    toBe(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().getInnerHtml());
};
```

Comment: this is not a solution for an input element: it is empty everytime

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way to compare an element with the focused one without relaying to any attributes:

```
element(by.css('div.my-class')).equals(browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement())
    .then(equals => expect(equals).toBe(true));
```