# Adding multiple values from promises [Protractor]

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have two input text boxes and one label on my page. I want to get the numbers from all three elements, add the two text box numbers together, then check if the sum equals the label. How would I go about this?

This is what I have so far, but it's not been working for me. It seems that getAttribute returns a value with apostrophes around the number. If I try to use "parseInt" it returns "NaN"

```
element(by.id('textbox1')).getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
textbox1value = value;
});

element(by.id('textbox2')).getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
textbox2value = value;
});

element(by.id('label1')).getText().then(function(value){
label1value = value;
});

expect(textbox1value + textbox2value).toEqual(label1value);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually solve it with `promise.all()`:

```
var first = element(by.id('textbox1')).getAttribute('value'),
    second = element(by.id('textbox2')).getAttribute('value'),
    total = element(by.id('label1')).getText();

protractor.promise.all([first, second, total]).then(function (values) {
    expect(parseInt(values[0]) + parseInt(values[1])).toEqual(parseInt(values[2]));
});
```

Or, you can also use [`q` promise library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and it's `spread()` syntactic sugar:

```
Q.all([first, second, total]).spread(function (first, second, total) {
    first = parseInt(first);
    second = parseInt(second);
    total = parseInt(total);

    expect(first + second).toEqual(total);
});
```

And, you can also replace `protractor.promise` with `q`, see:

- [Spreading promises in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887795/spreading-promises-in-protractor)