# Take elements while a condition evaluates to true (extending ElementArrayFinder)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iteration, protractor

We have a menu represented as a `ul->li` list (simplified):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="filterItem in filterCtrl.filterPanelCfg track by filterItem.name"
        ng-class="{'divider': filterItem.isDivider}" class="ng-scope">
        <a href="" class="ng-binding"> Menu Item 1</a>
    </li>
    ...
    <li ng-repeat="filterItem in filterCtrl.filterPanelCfg track by filterItem.name"
        ng-class="{'divider': filterItem.isDivider}" class="ng-scope">
        <a href="" class="ng-binding"> Menu Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where somewhere at position N, there is a divider, which can be identified by *evaluating* `filterItem.isDivider` or by checking the text of the `a` link (in case of a divider, it's empty).

Now, the goal is to get all of the menu items that are located before the divider. How would you approach the problem?

---

My current approach is rather generic - to extend `ElementArrayFinder` and add `takewhile()` function (inspired by Python's [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)). Here is how I've implemented it (based on [`filter()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.js#L201)):

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.takewhile = function(whileFn) {
    var self = this;
    var getWebElements = function() {
        return self.getWebElements().then(function(parentWebElements) {
            var list = [];
            parentWebElements.forEach(function(parentWebElement, index) {
                var elementFinder =
                    protractor.ElementFinder.fromWebElement_(self.ptor_, parentWebElement, self.locator_);

                list.push(whileFn(elementFinder, index));
            });
            return protractor.promise.all(list).then(function(resolvedList) {
                var filteredElementList = [];
                for (var index = 0; index < resolvedList.length; index++) {
                    if (!resolvedList[index]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    filteredElementList.push(parentWebElements[index])
                }
                return filteredElementList;
            });
        });
    };
    return new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(this.ptor_, getWebElements, this.locator_);
};
```

And, here is how I'm using it:

```
this.getInclusionFilters = function () {
    return element.all(by.css("ul.dropdown-menu li")).takewhile(function (inclusionFilter) {
        return inclusionFilter.evaluate("!filterItem.isDivider");
    });
};
```

But, the test is just hanging until `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` is reached on the `takewhile()` call.

If I put `console.log`s into the loop and after, I can see that it correctly pushes the elements before the divider and stops when it reaches it. I might be missing something here.

Using protractor 2.2.0.

---

Also, let me know if I'm overcomplicating the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just go through `ul li a` elements while they gave you something from getText(), and store them to some array, or do something with them directly in that loop?

```
var i = 0;
var el = element.all(by.css('ul li a'));
var tableItems = [];
(function loop() {
    el.get(i).getText().then(function(text){
        if(text){
            tableItems.push(el.get(i));
            i+=1;
            loop();
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thank you for the option! What I'm not satisfied is that, in this case, as a result I'll get an array of elements and not an ElementArrayFinder which makes it inconvenient to work with later - for instance, I won't be able to call `getText()` on it and get an array of texts, or use `map()`, `each()` or other functional syntax available in protractor..but, in general, it gets the job done, I agree.

Comment: Given that now I can [make an `ElementArrayFinder` instance out of an array of element finders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599679/making-elementarrayfinder-from-an-array-of-elementfinders), this option becomes the way-to-go for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

`takewhile()` actually worked for me once I removed the `protractor.promise = require("q");` from `onPrepare()` - this was there to replace `protractor.promise` with `q` on the fly to be able to use the syntactic sugar like [`spread()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887795/spreading-promises-in-protractor). Apparently, *it is not safe to use `q` in place of `protractor.promise`*.

All I have to do now is to add this to `onPrepare()`:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.takewhile = function(whileFn) {
    var self = this;
    var getWebElements = function() {
        return self.getWebElements().then(function(parentWebElements) {
            var list = [];
            parentWebElements.forEach(function(parentWebElement, index) {
                var elementFinder =
                    protractor.ElementFinder.fromWebElement_(self.ptor_, parentWebElement, self.locator_);

                list.push(whileFn(elementFinder, index));
            });
            return protractor.promise.all(list).then(function(resolvedList) {
                var filteredElementList = [];
                for (var index = 0; index < resolvedList.length; index++) {
                    if (!resolvedList[index]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    filteredElementList.push(parentWebElements[index])
                }
                return filteredElementList;
            });
        });
    };
    return new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(this.ptor_, getWebElements, this.locator_);
};
```

The usage is very similar to `filter()`:

```
element.all(by.css("ul li a")).takewhile(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text;
    });
});
```

FYI, [proposed to make `takewhile()` built-in](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2521).