# Making ElementArrayFinder from an array of ElementFinders

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

This is a follow-up question to [Take elements while a condition evaluates to true (extending ElementArrayFinder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572299/take-elements-while-a-condition-evaluates-to-true-extending-elementarrayfinder) topic and @cvakiitho's answer in particular.

**The problem:**

After executing the following code:

```
var i = 0;
var el = element.all(by.css('ul li a'));
var tableItems = [];
(function loop() {
    el.get(i).getText().then(function(text){
        if(text){
            tableItems.push(el.get(i));
            i+=1;
            loop();
        }
    });
}());
```

`tableItems` would contain an array of `ElementFinder` instances - or, to put it simple - an array of web elements.

**The Question:**

Is it possible to convert an array of `ElementFinder`s to an [`ElementArrayFinder`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e2b838b60d4430d34347e668e6e8e884faadc0ee/lib/element.js#L10) instance?

**The Motivation:**

The reason I want this is to have all of the convenient `ElementArrayFinder` functional utilities, like [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map), [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each), [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) and to be able to call `getText()` on it producing a promise which would resolve into an array of element texts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Constructor of `ElementArrayFinder`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.2.0/lib/element.js#L63) basically requires two main arguments: protractor instance and a function `getWebElements`, which should return a promise resolving to an array of Web Elements. As soon as every `ElementFinder` has a method to get it's Web Element called `getWebElement`, it is possible to create such a function.

```
var arrayOfElementFinders = [el1, el2, el3];

var getWebElements = function () {

    // create array of WebElements from array of ElementFinders
    var webElements = arrayOfElementFinders.map(function (ef) {
        return ef.getWebElement();
    });

    // immediately resolve and return promise
    return protractor.promise.fulfilled(webElements);
};
```

Now when all requirements are satisfied, it is possible to create a new instance of `ElementArrayFinder`:

```
var elArrayFinder = new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(protractor, getWebElements);
```

To make it easy to use I would add a static method to `ElementArrayFinder` constructor and include it somewhere before tests start:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.fromArray = function (arrayOfElementFinders) {
    var getWebElements = function () {
        var webElements = arrayOfElementFinders.map(function (ef) {
            return ef.getWebElement();
        })
        return protractor.promise.fulfilled(webElements);
    };
    return new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(protractor, getWebElements);
};
```

And use it in tests like:

```
var elArrayFinder = protractor.ElementArrayFinder.fromArray(arrayOfElementFinders);
```