# How to extend ElementFinder object in ProtractorJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Durring some experiments with protractorJS i noticed that there is no easy way to extend (inherit) ElementFinder object from protractor to add own functions.

For example, i want to create object Checkbox, that would have additional method - check() - should switch checkbox depending on result of isSelected().

I come up with the code -

```
var ElementFinder = require('protractor/lib/element.js').ElementFinder;
var ElementArrayFinder = require('protractor/lib/element.js').ElementArrayFinder;

class CheckBox extends ElementFinder {
    constructor(loc) {
      var getWebElements = function () {
        var ptor = browser;
        var locator = loc;
        return ptor.waitForAngular().then(function() {
          if (locator.findElementsOverride) {
            return locator.findElementsOverride(ptor.driver, null, ptor.rootEl);
          } else {
            return ptor.driver.findElements(locator);
          }
        });
      }
  var ArrayFinderFull = new ElementArrayFinder(browser, getWebElements, loc);
  super(browser, ArrayFinderFull);
}

    check() {
    return this.isSelected().then(selected => selected? this.click() : null)
    }
}
```

But getWebElements is copy-paste from protractor/element.js -
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.1.0/lib/element.js#L131

This copy-paste flustrating me. I think there should be more proper way to extend ElementFinder.

Does anyone inherited ElementFinder in protractorJS?

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue, I need to achieve same thing?

Comment: @shiva , partially. Please see my answer below about lib that i created. You can find code examples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is much simplier to extend ElementFinder, i calling this - page fragments.

I even created lib to solve this issue (PRs welcome!) - https://github.com/Xotabu4/protractor-element-extend

For now it only works with ElementFinder, but i want to be able to extend 
ElementArrayFinders as well (planned for 2.0.0 version)

#### UPDATE

Support for ElementArrayFinder inheritance is added.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure this would help, but here is [something we did recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572299/take-elements-while-a-condition-evaluates-to-true-extending-elementarrayfinder) to have a `takewhile()` method available on an `ElementArrayFinder`. We've put the following into `onPrepare()`:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.takewhile = function(whileFn) {
    var self = this;
    var getWebElements = function() {
        return self.getWebElements().then(function(parentWebElements) {
            var list = [];
            parentWebElements.forEach(function(parentWebElement, index) {
                var elementFinder =
                    protractor.ElementFinder.fromWebElement_(self.ptor_, parentWebElement, self.locator_);

                list.push(whileFn(elementFinder, index));
            });
            return protractor.promise.all(list).then(function(resolvedList) {
                var filteredElementList = [];
                for (var index = 0; index < resolvedList.length; index++) {
                    if (!resolvedList[index]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    filteredElementList.push(parentWebElements[index])
                }
                return filteredElementList;
            });
        });
    };
    return new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(this.ptor_, getWebElements, this.locator_);
};
```

And now we can use `takewhile` on the result of `element.all()`:

```
element.all(by.repeater("row in rows")).takewhile(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return some_condition_to_be_true;
    });
});
```