# Slicing elements in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

In Protractor, we can get a single element from an array by *index* via:

```
var elements = element.all(by.css(".myclass"));
elements.get(1);
elements.first();
elements.last();
```

But, is it possible to *slice* out a subarray out of the array of elements in a similar fashion?

Ideally, we'd like to have something like:

```
var subelements = elements.slice(2, 5);
// subelements is also an ElementArrayFinder
// we can call "filter()", "map()" etc on subelements
```

---

I think we would need to extend `ElementArrayFinder` by defining a custom `protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.slice()` method (similar to how it was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572299/take-elements-while-a-condition-evaluates-to-true-extending-elementarrayfinder)).

<sub>I've also noticed [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/2822), but it has not been merged and it is not active anymore.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-box solution i afraid.
I believe you can implement slicing with .filter()

First that come to my mind:

```
function slice (arrayFinder, from, to) {
    return arrayFinder.filter(function(elem, index) {
        if (index >= from && index < to) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @alecxe you are welcome, btw i like to read you answers for protractor

Comment: Thanks. And I'm learning from yours. Keep posting more answers!

Comment: Please avoid `if (...) {return true;}` when possible, it adds a level of indentation and is more complex to read for other developpers. Here, you can just use `return index >= from && index < to;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice directly on the resolved promise:

```
$$('a')
  .then(elements => elements.slice(3, 8))
  .then(elements => console.log("Count ", elements.length));
```

You cold also extend the `ElementArrayFinder` prototype:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.slice = function(begin, end) {
  return this.then(elements => elements.slice(begin, end));
};

$$('a')
  .slice(3, 8)
  .then(elements => console.log("Count ", elements.length));
```

And with a filter:

```
$$('a')
  .filter((e, i) => i >= 3 && i < 8)
  .then(elements => console.log("Count ", elements.length));
```

Comment: That wont work, since element() and element.all() return ElementFinder and ArrayElementFinder objects, not promises. So $$('a').then() will fail with no such method. .filter() also returns new ArrayElementFinder

Comment: @Xotabu4, Yes it works. The extended `.slice` returns a promise that resolves to an array of values. To make it return and ArrayElementFinder, it is as simple as wrapping the promise in a new instance of `ArrayElementFinder`.