# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined after upgrading to Protractor 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

Recently, we've upgraded to [Protractor 4.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400) and our tests started to fail immediately with:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Failing in `onPrepare()` on the following line:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.takewhile = function(whileFn) {
   // ...
};
```

Here we are [extending `ElementArrayFinder` to support `takewhile` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572299/take-elements-while-a-condition-evaluates-to-true-extending-elementarrayfinder).

Looks like `protractor.ElementArrayFinder` is now *undefined*.
How should we be extending `ElementArrayFinder` in Protractor 4?

<sup>I don't see anything related in the breaking changes in the changelog.</sup>

---

Issue tracker link: [Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined (Protractor 4 upgrade problem)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3377).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `ElementFinder` and `ElementArrayFinder` are no longer exposed in the `protractor` namespace. You could simply import them with require:

```
var ElementFinder = require('protractor/built/element').ElementFinder;
var ElementArrayFinder = require('protractor/built/element').ElementArrayFinder;

ElementArrayFinder.prototype.takewhile = function(whileFn) {
    ...
};
```