# Using Protractor to select a child div id

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm having an issue pulling a child `div` **ID** for each row in the `row.map` function below.

In other words, for each row element I iterate, I want to pull `rowId` attrib:

```
<div id="rowId_21">
```

Here's an Html snippet:

```html
<div ng-repeat="row in vm.sourceData.data" ng-init="thatRow=$index">
 <div id="rowId_21" ng-class-odd="'row-2'" ng-class-even="'row-3'" >
   <div ng-repeat="column in  vm.sourceData.columns" >    
     <div ng-if="row[column.field].length !== 0" class="ng-scope highlight21"> 
   <span ng-bind-html="row[column.field] | changeNegToPrenFormat" vm.highlightedrow="" class="ng-binding"> 
                Sales
         </span>
     </div>    
   </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div ng-repeat="row in vm.sourceData.data" ng-init="thatRow=$index">
  <div id="rowId_22" ng-class-odd="'row-2'" ng-class-even="'row-3'" ng-class="vm.hideRow(row)" class="row-3 height-auto">
  <!-- ... -->
 </div>
</div>
```

I start with pulling the `rows` object, then I iterate them :

```js
// pulls the data rows
var selDataRows = '.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper';
var rows = element(by.css(selDataRows)).all(by.repeater('row in vm.sourceData.data'));

rows.map(function (row, idx) {            
  //var thisRowId = row.element(by.css('div[id^="rowId_"]'));  // *** RETURNS NULL
  
  var thisRowId = row.all(by.xpath("descendant::div[starts-with(@id, 'rowId')]"));
  
  thisRowId.getText().then(function(txt){              
      // RETURNS A VERY LONG ID: [ '7\n4\n41\n113\n3.3\n(34)\n(1.1)\n7...]
      console.log('--- Curr Div ID: ', txt);
  });
  
}).
then(function(){            
console.log('*** Rows.Map Done.');            
});
```

I thought this would pull the first child id (i.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors ):

`by.css('div[id^="rowId_"]')` ,

or perhaps this way:

`by.xpath("descendant::div[starts-with(@id, 'rowId')]")` ,

however neither seems to be working.

Advice appreciated...

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to *return from the mapping function*. And, use `.getAttribute()` method to get the `id` attribute:

```
var selDataRows = '.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper';
var rows = element(by.css(selDataRows)).all(by.repeater('row in vm.sourceData.data'));

rows.map(function (row) {            
    return row.element(by.xpath("descendant::div[starts-with(@id, 'rowId')]")).getAttribute("id").then(function(rowId) {              
        return rowId;
    });
}).then(function(ids) {            
    console.log(ids);            
});
```

Comment: Hello friend, and thnk you for responding. Turns out I need the rowId within the mapping function; however, looks like I made an error by using `thisRowId.getText()` instead of  `getAttribute("id")`. I'll retest first thing in morning. THANKS !

Comment: @bob.mazzo got it, yeah, this should help. By the way, if you don't need the array of ids later, see if `each()` is a better tool for the job than `map()`. Thanks, let's grab a beer or two sometime in the city! (ping me through linkedin if interested!)

Comment: I was considering `.each()` but I forget exactly what happened. I'll revisit that idea. +1

Comment: After changing that key line to `getAttribute("id")`, I noticed that this line also pulls the row id - `row.element(by.css('div[id^="rowId_"]'))` . It might be just slightly faster using by.css() instead of xpath().

Comment: how do I exit the `.each()` under a certain condition ? I see that `return false` only break out of the current iteration, then moves to the next one.

Comment: @bob.mazzo I think you may be interested in using the `takewhile()` function, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572299/take-elements-while-a-condition-evaluates-to-true-extending-elementarrayfinder. Hope that helps.