# How JavaScript closures can help in Protractor test automation?

Tags: javascript, protractor

As I am working in protractor test automation and slowly diving into more & more advanced JavaScript features, I am wondering how can I take advantage of closure feature in Protractor test automation.

> What are those typical test automation situations where closures might prove
>   a useful feature to use?

I am asking this question purely from UI test automation perspective, not in general JavaScript programming. I would love to hear from senior folks who are using a protractor on an advanced level in large scale projects and share their experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some closure use cases that we've been using in our test automation project:

- when a Page Object method has a promise resolution function in which you need to access the other Page Object fields or methods, you need to create a closure:

  ```
  var SelectEnvironmentPage = function () {    
      this.title = this.container.element(by.css("b.modal-title"));
      this.goButton = element(by.id("selEnvBtnGo"));

      this.passIfPresent = function () {
          var self = this;
          this.title.isPresent().then(function (isTitlePresent) {
              if (isTitlePresent) {
                  self.goButton.click().then(function () {
                      helpers.passMaxSessionPopup();
                  });
              }
          });
      };
  };
  ```
- when [extending `ElementArrayFinder` methods and defining the `getWebElements()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745810/771848)