# protractor: filter until finding first valid element

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am doing e2e testing on a site that contains a table which I need to iterate "until" finding one that doesn't fail when I click on it.

I tried it using `filter` and it is working:

```
this.selectValidRow = function () {
    return Rows.filter(function (row, idx) {
        row.click();
        showRowPage.click();
        return errorMessage.isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
            if (!displayed) {
                rowsPage.click(); // go back to rows Page, all the rows
                return true;
            }
        });
    }).first().click();
};
```

The problem here is that it is iterating **all** available rows, and I only need the first one that is valid (that doesn't show an `errorMessage`).

The problem with my current approach is that it is taking too long, as my current table could contain hundreds of rows.

Is it possible to `filter` (or a different method) and stop iterating when first valid occurrence appears?, or could someone come up with a better approach?

Comment: But how do you know is a valid row?, just by clicking on it and seeing there is no error?

Comment: yes, in my case, I really need to access one of those rows page, and some of the rows give errors (because their respective pages don't exist or something). I just want a way to find one of the rows that won't give me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer a non-protractor approach of handling this situation, I would suggest [async.whilst](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst). async is a very popular module and its highly likely that your application is using it. I wrote below code here in the editor, but it should work, you can customize it based on your needs. Hopefully you get an idea of what I'm doing here.

```
var found = false, count = 0;
async.whilst(function iterator() {
   return !found &&  count < Rows.length;
}, function search(callback) {
    Rows[count].click();
    showRowPage.click();
    errorMessage.isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
        if (!displayed) {
            rowsPage.click(); // go back to rows Page, all the rows
            found = true; //break the loop
            callback(null, Rows[count]); //all good, lets get out of here
        } else {
           count = count + 1;
           callback(null); //continue looking
        }
    });
}, function aboutToExit(err, rowIwant) {
    if(err) {
      //if search sent an error here;
    }
    if(!found) {
      //row was not found;
    }
    //otherwise as you were doing
    rowIwant.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `filter()` and other built-in Protractor "functional programming" methods would not solve the "stop iterating when first valid occurrence appears" case. You need the "take some elements while some condition evaluates to true" (like the `itertools.takewhile()` in Python world).

Fortunately, you can *extend `ElementArrayFinder`* (preferably in `onPrepare()`) and add the `takewhile()` method:

- [Take elements while a condition evaluates to true (extending ElementArrayFinder)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32572299/771848)

Note that I've proposed it to be built-in, but the feature request is still open:

- [Add takewhile() method to ElementArrayFinder](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2521)