# Capturing scroll on click of a button

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have a webpage where there is scroll happening to next section within the webpage on click of a button. Can someone please suggest how to capture that scroll? Code is with in the anchor tag and href is pointing to # to scroll to next section in page. I am not sure how to validate if scroll actually worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert/check few things in this case:

- the [current URL](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl) to point to the correct `#` section:

  ```
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("https://url.com/mypage#myparagraph");
  ```
- [check](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue) the [`scrollTop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript) position of the `body` element (assuming it is what is scrolled - or the other scrollable container):

  ```
  var body = $("body");
  expect(body.getCssValue("scrollTop")).toEqual("someValue");  // or apply the "greater than" check
  ```
- check the [current active element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756276/771848) (assuming there is an element focused once the "anchor" paragraph is becoming active)
- solution based on your suggestion to use [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) - compare the value before and after the click:

  ```
  browser.executeScript('return window.pageYOffset;').then(function (offsetBefore) {
      offsetBefore = parseInt(offsetBefore);
      button.click();

      browser.executeScript('return window.pageYOffset;').then(function (offsetAfter) { 
           offsetAfter = parseInt(offsetAfter);
           expect(offsetAfter).toBeGreaterThan(offsetBefore);
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately none of these work for me.
1. I cannot use first one as my browser URL is not changing. It remains same exactly the way it was earlier.
2. I am not able to check scrollTop position. Below commands are not working on my application. I used below code and it print some long list of commands.
``
    var body = $("body");
     var scrollposition = body.getCssValue("scrollTop");
    console.log(scrollposition);   
``
.ElementFinder {
  browser_:
   ProtractorBr
3. On click of button, browser is not focusing on any element. It just display map.I do not think it focus

Comment: Below solution worked but i did not wanted to specify position in my script. I am afraid script might fail if executed in different environment.
`      browser.executeScript('return window.pageYOffset;').then(function(pos) {
        expect(pos).toBe(829)});  `
Let me know if there is any better solution.

Comment: @NewWorld ah okay, well, you can get the `pageYOffset` value before the click and after and compare the values. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Worked very well.

Comment: Checking the `pageYOffset` before and after will not work if the link is not already within the window. The driver will scroll it into the view before clicking on it. So the `pageYOffset` will increase even if the click fails to jump to the reference.

Comment: @FlorentB. ah yeah, the scroll into view part is preventing this to properly work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could check that the anchor is scrolled at the top of the window by checking the positon relative to the viewport with `getBoundingClientRect()` :

```
browser.get('https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver');
$("[href='#capabilities']").click();

// assert that the position of the anchor relative to the top border of the window is less than 16 pixels.
var anchor = $('#h-capabilities');
var isCloseToTop = browser.executeScript(e => !(e.getBoundingClientRect().top >> 4), anchor);
expect(isCloseToTop).toBeTruthy();
```

Note that if the anchor is at the very bottom of the document, the anchor will not be at the top of the window, but somewhere within.
So you should also consider this case with a more generic solution:

```
browser.get('https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver');

$("[href='#informative-references']").click();
expect(isScrolledTop($('#h-informative-references'))).toBeTruthy();

function isScrolledTop(element) {
  return browser.executeScript(function(elem) {
    var doc = elem.ownerDocument,
      viewHeight = doc.defaultView.innerHeight,
      docBottom = doc.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
      box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return box.top > -1 && (box.top < 25 || (docBottom - viewHeight) < 25);
  }, element);
}
```